# Timer Tick more than 1 time at once

Tags: c#, timer

I am making a program where the timer1 should activate another timer2 and then stop, in timer2 i activate timer1 again and stop timer2 and so it goes on and then I have a text log where it write the progress down. And here is the problem, first its starts with 2 of Timer1 tick written out then 2 of timer 2 then it gets multiplied by 2 so its 4 next time then 8 then 16 so forth and I just want it to be 1 timer1 than 1 timer2 then its starts over again, I can't see what's wrong.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonStart.Enabled = false;
    buttonStop.Enabled = true;

    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); 
    timer1.Interval = (1000);             
    timer1.Enabled = true;                       
    timer1.Start();

}

private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonStart.Enabled = true;
    buttonStop.Enabled = false;

    timer1.Stop();
    timer2.Stop();
}

private void LogWrite(string txt)
{
    textBoxCombatLog.AppendText(txt + Environment.NewLine);
    textBoxCombatLog.SelectionStart = textBoxCombatLog.Text.Length;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogWrite(TimeDate + "player hit");

    timer1.Stop();

    timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
    timer2.Interval = (1000);
    timer2.Enabled = true;
    timer2.Start();


}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogWrite(TimeDate + "mob hit");

    timer2.Stop();

    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = (1000);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();

}
```

Comment: You should only do these lines timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick); once and only once (so remove them from the button click into the load/init of your form

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605726/how-to-make-timer-keep-runing-while-loop-wait-for-another-time-result/16606866#16606866) answer to a similar question on why conventional timers normally aren't used in games.

Comment: If the Interval() for both will always be the same, then just use one Timer and toggle a boolean to indicate who is currently attacking...

Answer (score 2):

on `timer1_tick` you add event to `timer2.tick` event, so every time when `timer1_tick` function raises, you add one more event listener to `timer2`, but never remove old event handlers, the same situation with timer2_tick.

My advice to you is add these lines to your constructor and remove these lines from other functions:

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); 
timer1.Interval = (1000);             
timer1.Enabled = true;   

timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
timer2.Interval = (1000);
timer2.Enabled = true;
```

If you will do that, your timers will call always only once function per tick.

Comment: it did kinda work, but there is still one problem tho, it does still write 2 lines all the time instead of 1, i put the Eventhandler in the start button this time. dont understand why it does like that.

Comment: because you have somewhere added listener to function `timer1_tick` or `timer2_tick` on `timer1.tick` or `timer2.tick`, so check your code and ensure that you have only one event listener for each function.

Comment: What do you mean with "listener" ?

Comment: `timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);` i mean thant event listener is `timer1_tick`. sorry for my bad english, but i thinked that event listener and event handler is the same in programming

Comment: Do you mean that i have timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
is inside the timer1.Tick form ? and that i should not have that ? beacuse if thats the point, Epsli0neR already told me what to do.

Comment: I mean that you must have only one `timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);` and one `timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);` which also must not be inside function which is raises few times, for example in button.click function

Comment: But if the button is clicked only once ?

Comment: then is nothing serious, but still, in button click you simple can call stop() and start() for timer, while these event handlers will handle events. by the way, why you want add event handlers in button.click function when you can assign these handlers when page is loaded? P.S. I`m finished my discution, if you don't know how write good code, then start reading books about programing and other  manuals

Comment: i cant for some reason, says that the timer1. ... are a field but are used like a type Btw been there dont that

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is what @Epsil0neR means...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = (1000);
        timer1.Enabled = false;

        timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
        timer2.Interval = (1000);
        timer2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonStart.Enabled = false;
        buttonStop.Enabled = true;

        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer2.Stop();

        buttonStart.Enabled = true;
        buttonStop.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void LogWrite(string txt)
    {
        textBoxCombatLog.AppendText(txt + Environment.NewLine);
        textBoxCombatLog.SelectionStart = textBoxCombatLog.Text.Length;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();

        LogWrite(TimeDate + "player hit");

        timer2.Start();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Stop();

        LogWrite(TimeDate + "mob hit");

        timer1.Start();
    }

    private string TimeDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ": "; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, but that does still no change the problem that it type "mob hit" 2 times in a row and "player hit" 2 times in a row instead of just a singel time

Comment: i can post a screen shot do describe what i mean

Comment: Most likely you had **already** wired up the two timers thru your IDE, and don't need to do it via code.  Remove these lines: `timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);` and `timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);`