# Form2 Not Opening?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I am making a Video game using microsoft Visual c++, I am coding all of this in CLR language, But I this weird problem....

For some reason Whenever I try and open form 2 with Form 1 all I get are these errors...

```
  *1>------ Build started: Project: Retaliation, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  1>  Form2.cpp
  1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio       2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(431): error C2065: 'Form2' : undeclared       identifier
  1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio       2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(431): error C2065: 'f2' : undeclared       identifier
  1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(431): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Form2'
  1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(432): error C2065: 'f2' : undeclared identifier
  1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio       2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(432): error C2227: left of '->Show' must       point to class/struct/union/generic type
  1>          type is ''unknown-type''
  1>  Retaliation.cpp
  1>  Generating Code...
  ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========*
```

Here is my code for form 1...

```
   #pragma once
   #include "stdAfx.h"
   #include "Form2.h"
   #include "Form1.h"

   namespace Retaliation {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;
/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    String^ CharName;
    String^ Race;
    String^ Gender;
    String^ Specialty;
    String^ Friend;
    int YesorNo;
    int ExitChoice;
    int TimerValue;
int MonsterN;
int EnemyHp;
int Dm;
int Energy;
int Action;
int Rage;
int MaxMana;
int MaxRage;
int MaxEnergy;
int Save;
// 1 = Earth pony 2 = Pegasus 3 = unicorn
int Lv;
int XpR;
     int Xp;
int A;
int D;
int Hp;
int MaxHp;
int Magic;
int Mana;
int Agility;
int Gold;
String ^Enpowerment;
// 1 = Friendship is Magic, 2 = Music is Magic, 3 = Darkness is Magic, 4 = Light is     Magic, 5 = Chaos is Magic
// End of leveling thread
int Checkpoint;
int FriendNameN;
int SavePoint;
int MenuChoice;
int RightMenuChoice;
int RestartFile;
int Answer;
int EnemyA;
int EnemyD;
int EnemyLv;
int EnemyMana;
int EnemyMagic;
int EnemyAgility;
int Random;
String ^ EName;
int Damage;
int Survivors;
int SavedSurvivors;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^  timer1;
public: 
    int MainActions;


    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //

    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;



private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;


private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox3;
private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>


      #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources =   (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->pictureBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->pictureBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this- >components));
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  > (this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  > (this->pictureBox2))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox3))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^   >(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.Image")));
        this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, -3);
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(600, 295);
        this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 230);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(127, 43);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button1->Text = L"Start Game";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,   &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(313, 212);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(120, 42);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->button2->Text = L"New Game";
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button2->Visible = false;
        this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(143, 212);
        this->button3->Name = L"button3";
        this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(120, 42);
        this->button3->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button3->Text = L"Load Game";
        this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button3->Visible = false;
        this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button3_Click);
        // 
        // pictureBox2
        // 
        this->pictureBox2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
        this->pictureBox2->BackgroundImage =  (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources- >GetObject(L"pictureBox2.BackgroundImage")));
        this->pictureBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, -3);
        this->pictureBox2->Name = L"pictureBox2";
        this->pictureBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(86, 81);
        this->pictureBox2->TabIndex = 4;
        this->pictureBox2->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox2->Visible = false;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(92, -3);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 5;
        this->label1->Text = L"     ";
        this->label1->Visible = false;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(358, 87);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(199, 98);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 9;
        this->label2->Text = L"None";
        this->label2->Visible = false;
        // 
        // button4
        // 
        this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(463, 13);
        this->button4->Name = L"button4";
        this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button4->TabIndex = 12;
        this->button4->Text = L"Yes";
        this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button4->Visible = false;
        this->button4->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button4_Click);
        // 
        // button5
        // 
        this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(463, 43);
        this->button5->Name = L"button5";
        this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button5->TabIndex = 13;
        this->button5->Text = L"No";
        this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button5->Visible = false;
        this->button5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button5_Click);
        // 
        // pictureBox3
        // 
        this->pictureBox3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
        this->pictureBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 84);
        this->pictureBox3->Name = L"pictureBox3";
        this->pictureBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(165, 208);
        this->pictureBox3->TabIndex = 14;
        this->pictureBox3->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox3->Visible = false;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(463, 212);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 15;
        this->textBox1->Visible = false;
        this->textBox1->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_TextChanged_1);
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this->timer1->Interval = 1000;
        this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(598, 285);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Retaliation";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox2))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox3))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
    #pragma endregion
    public:int MoviePlay;
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             //
             this -> button2 -> Visible = true;
             this -> button3 -> Visible = true;
             this -> button1 -> Visible = false;
             this -> pictureBox1 -> Load("Derpy.jpg");
             //
         }
       private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         if (YesorNo == 0){
             this -> button4 -> Visible = true;
         this -> button2 -> Visible = false;
         this -> button5 -> Visible = true;
         this -> button3 -> Visible = false;
         this -> label2 -> Visible = true;
         this -> label2 -> Text = "Are you Sure?";
         this -> YesorNo = 1;
         }
         else if (YesorNo == 5)
         {
             Gender = "Female";
             this -> label2 -> Text = "What is your Race??"; 
             this -> button4 -> Text = "Earth Pony";
             this -> button5 -> Text = "Unicorn";
             this -> button2 -> Visible = true;
             this -> button2 -> Text = "Pegasus";
             YesorNo = 6;
         }
         else if (YesorNo == 6)
         {
             Race = "Pegasus";
             this -> button2 -> Visible = false;
             this -> button4 -> Visible = false;
             this -> button5 -> Visible = false;
             label2 -> Text = "Thank You For Playing!!";
             YesorNo = 7;
             this -> timer1 -> Start();
         }
     }
          private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

     }
      private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         if (YesorNo == 1)
         {
             this -> label2 -> Text = "To Make your Pony Character, See  PonyMakin.txt in your Retaliation Folder, Your pony should have a invisible background...  If not check your background color For your pony!";
             button4 -> Text = "Show Pony";
             YesorNo = 2;
         }
         else if ( YesorNo == 2)
         {             
             this -> pictureBox3 -> Visible = true;
             this -> pictureBox3 -> Load("Outline Body Model.jpg");
             this -> pictureBox2 -> Visible = true;
             this -> pictureBox2 -> Load("OutlineModel.jpg");
             YesorNo = 3;
             this -> textBox1 -> Visible = true;
             this -> textBox1 -> Text = "Name?";
             this -> button5 -> Visible = false;
             this -> button4 -> Visible = false;
             this -> label2 -> Visible = false;

         }
         else if (YesorNo == 5)
         {
             Gender = "Male";
             this -> label2 -> Text = "What is your Race??"; 
             this -> button4 -> Text = "Earth Pony";
             this -> button5 -> Text = "Unicorn";
             this -> button2 -> Visible = true;
             this -> button2 -> Text = "Pegasus";
             YesorNo = 6;
         }
         else if (YesorNo == 6)
         {
             Race = "Earth_Pony";
             this -> button2 -> Visible = false;
             this -> button4 -> Visible = false;
             this -> button5 -> Visible = false;
             label2 -> Text = "Thank You For Playing!!";
             YesorNo = 7;
             this -> timer1 -> Start();
         }
     }

      private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         if (YesorNo == 1 || YesorNo == 2)
         {
             Application::Exit();
         }
         else if (YesorNo == 4)
         {
             this -> textBox1 -> Visible = false;
             this -> label2 -> Visible = true;
             this -> label2 -> Text = "What Is Your Gender?";
             this -> button4 -> Text = "Male";
             this -> button5 -> Text = "Female";
             this -> button4 -> Visible = true;
             this -> button5 -> Visible = true;
             YesorNo = 5;
         }
         else if (YesorNo == 5)
         {
             Gender = "Female";
             this -> label2 -> Text = "What is your Race??"; 
             this -> button4 -> Text = "Earth Pony";
             this -> button5 -> Text = "Unicorn";
             this -> button2 -> Visible = true;
             this -> button2 -> Text = "Pegasus";
             YesorNo = 6;
         }
         else if (YesorNo == 6)
         {
             Race = "Unicorn";
             this -> button2 -> Visible = false;
             this -> button4 -> Visible = false;
             this -> button5 -> Visible = false;
             label2 -> Text = "Thank You For Playing!!";
             YesorNo = 7;
             this -> timer1 -> Start();
         }
     }
       private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
           this -> button3 -> Text = "None yet";
     }
           private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         this -> label1 -> Visible = true;
         CharName = textBox1 -> Text;
         label1 -> Text = CharName;
         this -> button5 -> Visible = true;
         this -> button5 -> Text = "Done?";
         YesorNo = 4;
     }
        private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         TimerValue+= 1000;
         if (TimerValue == 5000)
         {
             Form2 ^ f2 = gcnew Form2;
             f2->Show();
             this->Hide();
             MoviePlay = 1;
             StreamWriter^ outFile = gcnew StreamWriter("Movie.txt");
             String^ Movie = MoviePlay.ToString();
             outFile->Write(Movie);
             outFile->Close();
             this -> timer1 -> Stop();

         }
     }
  };
  }
```

Why can I not open Form 2?
        2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(431): error C2065: 'Form2' : undeclared       identifier 
Is refering to...
      Form2 ^ f2 = gcnew Form2; at the bottom

Just in case it has to do with a problem in Form2...

```
   #pragma once
   #include "stdAfx.h"
   #include "Form1.h"
   #include "Form2.h"
   namespace Retaliation {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;


/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form2
/// </summary>
public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    int MoviePlay;

    Form2(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form2()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer^  MoviePlayer1;
protected: 

protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

     #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources =  (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form2::typeid));
        this->MoviePlayer1 = (gcnew AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->MoviePlayer1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // MoviePlayer1
        // 
        this->MoviePlayer1->Enabled = true;
        this->MoviePlayer1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->MoviePlayer1->Name = L"MoviePlayer1";
        this->MoviePlayer1->OcxState =  (cli::safe_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AxHost::State^  >(resources- >GetObject(L"MoviePlayer1.OcxState")));
        this->MoviePlayer1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(860, 497);
        this->MoviePlayer1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->MoviePlayer1->Enter += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,   &Form2::axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter);
        // 
        // Form2
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(859, 495);
        this->Controls->Add(this->MoviePlayer1);
        this->Name = L"Form2";
        this->Text = L"Form2";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::Form2_Load);
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->MoviePlayer1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #pragma endregion
private: System::Void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(System::Object^  sender,                 System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void Form2_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             if (MoviePlay == 1)
             {
                 MoviePlayer1->URL = "\\Scv183\\Scene1.mpeg";
             MoviePlayer1 -> Ctlcontrols -> play();
             }
         }
};
  }
```

Comment: Could you please shorten your code to something that's readable?

Comment: The errors are quite explicit: `Form1.h(431): error C2065: 'Form2' : undeclared       identifier`. Can you show us the file around the line 431 of `Form1.h`?

Comment: As I spotted a Timer in your code, maybe you want to take a second and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605726/how-to-make-timer-keep-runing-while-loop-wait-for-another-time-result/16606866#16606866)

Comment: @nvoigt No, to answer a question it is good to see all of it...

Comment: @Étienne that would be at the bottom...  Form2 ^ f2 = gcnew Form2;

Comment: It seems you didn't include the definition of Form2 in Form1.h, therefore the compiler doesn't understand `Form2 ^ f2 = gcnew Form2;`

Comment: @Darksly if you think so... I will not read that ton of code to answer you. Maybe someone else will. Good luck.

Comment: @nvoigt I am not sure How that is helping my problem...

Comment: Did you include Form2.h in Form1.h?

Comment: @Étienne Yes, At the top of Form1.h it says #include "Form2.h"

Comment: Is Form2 defined in Form2.h? To instantiate a Form2 object you need to include its class definition.

Comment: @Étienne I did put #include "Form2.h" into Form2.h if that is what you mean...

Comment: No I mean the class definition `public ref class Form2 ...`. Is this in Form2.h?

Comment: @Étienne I just added the form2 in the edit

Comment: So the "code for Form1" you posted is Form1.cpp? Are you including Form1.h in Form2.h?

Comment: @Étienne The code from Form1.h was copied from form1.h in my open visual c++ application, I do not have a form1.cpp, But strangely I do have a form2.cpp... to answer your question, yes I did include Form1.h into form2.h...

Comment: All form2.cpp has in it is #include "Form2.h"
and #include "StdAfx.h"

Comment: @Étienne How do I change what the source code is? the original source code is called Retaliation.cpp, But is looking for form2.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you have a circular dependency in your header files.
Your compiler is trying to compile Form2.cpp, where you include Form1.h, in Form1.h you include Form2.h, and in Form2.h you include Form1.h. You need to use a forward declaration, or to change your design so that you class are less coupled.

Moreover don't include a headerfile in itself..

More generally, you should not implement your function definitions in header files, but use your .cpp files for that. I also don't think you need to use precompiled headers (stdAfx.h), you should disable the check-box when you create a Visual Studio project.

Comment: So what do you recommend I do to solve this? delete Form2.cpp?

Comment: How do I change what the source code is? the original source code is called Retaliation.cpp, But is looking for form2.cpp

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I deleted the form2.cpp because the original main file is called Retaliation.cpp, But now i get 1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Form2.cpp': No such file or directory

Comment: I need it to recognize that Retaliation.cpp is its Source file

Comment: Recreate a form2.cpp manually, and then use right clic->rename in visual studio. You should get a good tutorial to understand better how the separation between header files and cpp files is working.

Comment: I Did what you said, but then it gave me a new error... Cannot open source file: Retaliation.cpp...

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

Create a new project. Form1 is created by default.

Create a button on Form1, double click it and paste the code below:

```
Form2^ testDialog = gcnew Form2;
testDialog->ShowDialog (this);
delete testDialog;
```

Go to solution explorer, right click the project and add a new Form and save it as Form2.

Double click Form1.cpp and you will see that it starts with the following lines:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
```

Edit it as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form2.h"
#include "Form1.h"
```

Note: The sequence of #include should not be changed.

Go ahead, run your project and enjoy!!!!

- Prasanth